# Index warning when setting up private APT repository

Tags: ubuntu, apt

I'm setting up a private APT repository for application deployment to a cluster of servers. I have set up the repository with reprepro essentially following the instructions [here](http://www.jejik.com/articles/2006/09/setting_up_and_managing_an_apt_repository_with_reprepro/), but using a pre-generated GPG key.

However, I keep getting this error when running apt-get update on the target servers:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://domU-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx.compute-1.internal/aptrepo/dists/oneiric/non-free/i18n/Index
No Hash entry in Release file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/domU-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx.compute-1.internal_aptrepo_dists_oneiric_non-free_i18n_Index
```

Do I need to worry about this? How do I fix it if I do?

Comment: I'm having the same problem and it's causing automated chef installations to fail so I find it beyond just annoying

Answer (score 5):

I was getting this issue for a while and it was failing our autmated build and googling around gave us nothing.  What we discovered was that issue was with our webserver configuration.  We build the repo using:

```
reprepro -V --ignore=wrongdistribution -b repository include precise &lt;some-package.changes&gt;
```

And then we mapped the repository directory to an nginx site.  The default nginx setup had the following configuration that was causing us pain:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ index.html;
```

This was mapping all files to resources and then anything that it didn't find was mapped to the index.html page.  So when apt was looking for dist/main/i18n/Index it was receiving an HTTP 200 but the file was not what apt was expecting, hence the error.  We replaced the try_files portion of the config with:

```
server {
    ...
    location / {
        ...
        try_files $uri $uri/; # index.html;
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

And then all requests to */i18n/Index were returning some HTTP error code and then it didn't bother trying to parse them and the issue went away.  Don't know if this helps you but it caused us 2 hrs of pain trying to figure out that we didn't have an issue with our debs or our repo but our webserver.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem but with Apache. The solution above can easily be ported to a .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteRule (.*) $1
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Having the same errors too, I had solved by adding theses lines in .htaccess :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  ## Folowing rule is tested for user-agent 'Debian APT-HTTP/1.3 (0.8.10.3)'
  ## used by apt-get, aptitude and synaptic -> send a 403 answer (Forbidden).
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Debian\ APT-HTTP
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^.* - [F,L]
</IfModule>
```